# Python YAML: Controlling output format

Tags: python, formatting, yaml

My file reads user input (like userid, password..). And sets the data to x.yml file.

The content of x.yml file is

```
{user: id}
```

But instead I want the content to be as

```
user: id
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm sorry, but I find it very hard to figure out what you are asking here. It would help if you included some code to show what you have tried, it'll make it much easier for us to help you. Perhaps you could also take a look at http://whathaveyoutried.com for a great article on how to ask good questions?

Comment: Also, have you tried using a [python YAML library](http://pyyaml.org/) to help you write out valid YAML?

Comment: import yaml
user = raw_input("Enter user id : ")
pwd = raw_input("Enter password : ")
stream = open(file1,"w")
yaml.dump({user:pwd},stream)

Is this the right way to insert data into yml file?
Running this file for the second time is adding another dict to yml file.
Can u help in this regard.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the python YAML library is the right tool for the job. To get the output you want, you need to pass the keyword argument `default_flow_style=False` to `yaml.dump`:

```python
>>> x = {"user" : 123}
>>> with open("output_file.yml", "w") as output_stream:
...     yaml.dump(x, output_stream, default_flow_style=False)
```

The file "output_file.yml" will contain:

```yaml
user: 123
```

Further information on how to customise `yaml.dump` are available at http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation.

Comment: This option also  seems to affect `lists` and `tuples` Is there a way to have it only affect `dicts`?

Alternatively, is there a way to tell it only to expand until a certain depth?

Comment: @Hyperplane did you ever sort this out? I'm running into a similar problem - I want to be rid of top-level dicts but keep second-level dicts and lists.

Comment: @skytwosea Nope, I remember that I tried building a custom formatter at some point but never finished it.